# Safari AJAX calls lose session / cookies in incognito?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, browser, safari

I'm having this problem only in Safari and only in incognito mode / private browsing (it works fine w/ normal browsing).

If I make a GET call via AJAX, my cookies are not being sent to the server, but if I put the same URL directly in the browser address bar, it works fine.

Example ("/path" being a route that just returns a cookie's value if it exists):

```
<script>
$.get("/path");
</script>
```

This fails, but if I go directly to the URL in the browser:

https://my.application.url/path

Then it works fine.

This is happening in the newest version of Safari (11.1.1).

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to fix / work around it?

Comment: Hi, it seams, that we got the same issue. Do you found how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with http vs https. It's an issue. Have you tried http?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I have tried both HTTP and HTTPS but I have not seen a difference, they both show the same behavior.